# How to use AVPlayer in UIAlertController in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This is my code AVPlayer :

```
    let video = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "MY_URL_VIDEO")!)
    let videoPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()
    videoPlayer.player = video
    present(videoPlayer, animated: true, completion: {
        video.play()
    })
```

And this is my UIAlertController code :

```
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Select", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Full HD 1080p", style: .default, handler: video.play()))
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .cancel))
    ac.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
    present(ac, animated: true)
```

And here's my error :(

[image]

Comment: The handler should be a closure, but instead you're calling a method `video.play()`.